# ASP.NET DataList for a single item

Tags: asp.net, controls, datalist

**Context:** In an ASP.NET application, I need the behavior of the ItemTemplate / EditItemTemplate that the  DataList control provides. However, I only need one item in my control, which makes the DataList seems like overkill.

**Question:** Is there a control in ASP.NET made to store a single item that has the template content behavior of the DataList and DataGrid? Should I use a DataList for only one item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the FormView or DetailsView? They are meant to display one item (at the time).

Comment: Thank you! It is precisely what I was looking for.